# Set Image using getAbsolutePath()

Tags: android, path, imageview

I'm trying to use custom gallery and trying to get the selected images and would like to display it in listview

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
if (extras != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fetchList.size(); i++) {
            Bitmap originBitmap = null;
            filepath = fetchList.get(i);
            newStringList.add(filepath);

            imgfilename = filepath.substring(filepath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            Uri selectedImage = Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath));
            File myFile = new File(selectedImage.getPath());
            myFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,myFile.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            listimage.setImageBitmap(myFile.getAbsolutePath());
            myStringList.add(imgfilename);
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this,
                    R.layout.custom_textview, R.id.listtext,
                    myStringList);
            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
 }
```

Now my question is how do I set the image to the image view using this path ?
If I use this  `listimage.setImageBitmap(myFile.getAbsolutePath());` I couldnt see the image.

Path I'm getting is : `/storage/emulated/0/`

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this way,

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: No the app is crashing by getting this error 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference

Comment: This means you are trying to set null bitmap in the image view. From your code i can see that you are getting path as /storage/emulated/0/ while it should be  /storage/emulated/0/<name of the image file>. As you can see in my answer it has complete path till image.jpg file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private AQuery aq = new AQuery(activity);

File imgFile = new File(filepath);
aq.id(imageView).image(imgFile, false, 300, new BitmapAjaxCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void callback(String url, ImageView iv, Bitmap bm, AjaxStatus status) {
                            iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
                        }
                    });
```